# iam user per application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For one of my business process I want to create IAM user for multiple application to access the same resource, I have thought of the following options:

1. Create 1 IAM user and use the credentials across the applications in the business
2. Create individual IAM user per application and use respective credentials

I went through https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/ and it mentions that IAM user can be an application or a system.

I understand 1 has an advantage that it simplifies the process with only a single IAM user to manage.

But 2 makes the applications independent of each other and provides fine-grained control over credentials.

What is the best practice followed in creation of IAM in this case and why?

Comment: Go with 2 and also use policies attached to the users/roles, so applications that access the same resources can all have the same policy attached (DRY: dont repeat yourself). If your applications run on EC2 use roles instead of users, try to avoid having to store credentials in your applications when possible.

Comment: thanks at0mzk, I will be having a credentials store so I will not be keeping them on EC2 instances and will be creating groups and policies for resource permissions. I am looking for data points for using 2, as following KISS principle would mean going with 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, AWS prefers creating individual IAM users for easier management and auditing. You can also revoke access to a specific app without affecting other system users. See [IAM Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).

I also quote from the [AWS Security Best Practices](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-security-best-practices.pdf) whitepaper.

> We strongly discourage the use of shared user identities, where
>   multiple entities share the same credentials.